# How to change textfield color (Vaadin)

Tags: java, vaadin, textfield

I am trying to change the `textField` **color**, but I can't reach the desired effect.

I found in browser DevTools the part, where `color` can be setted.

[image]

Is it part `[part='input-field']`

But when I created my own `.css` file with this information

```
.custom-text-field [part='input-field'] {
    flex-grow: 0;
    background: orange;
}
```

And I added this as `textField` class name

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
textField.addClassName("custom-text-field");
```

I didn't reach the result like in picture, but the DevTools showing, that my own class was used:

```
<vaadin-text-field class="custom-text-field" required="" has-label="" style="width: calc(99.9% - 0rem); margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px;"><input slot="input" type="text" id="vaadin-text-field-2" required="" aria-labelledby="label-vaadin-text-field-2"><label slot="label" id="label-vaadin-text-field-2" for="vaadin-text-field-2">Email</label><div slot="error-message" id="error-message-vaadin-text-field-2" hidden=""></div></vaadin-text-field>
```

Result:

[image]

How can I do it? Any ideas?

Comment: See the documentation for help: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/getting-started/#styling.get-started.shadow-dom-styling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.custom-text-field::part(input-field) {
  flex-grow: 0;
  background: orange;
}
```